# Stream classroom to student

Tags: web-apps, educational, chrome-os

Is there a good program that can telepresence a student into a classroom? I am thinking Google+ Hangouts, but is there a better program for this? Preferably, it should work on Chromebooks; alternatively a Windows program would be acceptable, too.

**UPDATE** with elaboration

I am looking for a program that can show the classroom to the student and possibly stream the computer screen.

Comment: @Izzy If not available for Chrome OS, the school also has Windows PCs. I am looking for a program that can show the classroom to the student and possibly stream the computer screen.

Comment: Thanks, I've integrated that with your question as well. // It might be just me (not seeing any answer yet rather indicates it's *not* just me ;), but I don't get the full idea of what you expect from such a program. If you feel it hard to list all requirements, maybe you could describe an "example session"? The program is running on a device in the school (?) – and where's the student? How does he access it (does that need a counterpart?), what are intended "interactions"?

Comment: What do you want to do that you can't do with Google+ Hangouts?  If you explain why Hangouts doesn't meet all your needs, it might help people help you find alternatives.